# How to use U substitution for the integral $\int\frac{8}{49+x^2}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

So, the following is my problem. 
$$\int\frac{8}{49+x^2}\,dx$$
I understand this. I should first take out the constant which is 8 so it'll be
$$8\int\frac{1}{49+x^2}\,dx$$
Then I should factor out the 49 no? So it'll be
$$\frac{8}{49}\int\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{49}}\,dx$$
Let $u=\dfrac{x}{7}$ and thus $du=\dfrac{1}{7}\,dx$. I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Good job, the next step is to evaluate $\displaystyle \dfrac 87 \int \dfrac{du}{u^2+1}$

Comment: So I'm kind of confused, where does the denominator of 49 go and why is it replaced with 7? @Amzoti

Comment: Try a trigonometric substitution.

Comment: @INTEGRALS: You used $u = \dfrac{x}{7}$, so, with that substitution, what does $\dfrac{x^2}{49}$ become (it is $u^2$)? Also, you have $du = \dfrac {1}{7} dx \implies dx = 7 du$. When you substitute those two thing in, you end up with the comment I show. Clear?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps 
$$\int\frac{8}{x^2+49}dx= 8\int\frac{1}{x^2+7^2}dx 
$$
$$=\frac{8}{7^2} \int\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{7^2}+1}dx =\frac{8}{7^2} \int\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{7}\right)^2+1}dx $$
Let $u=\frac{x}{7}$, then $du=\frac{1}{7}dx$. So now
$$ \frac{8}{7} \int\frac{1}{u^2+1}du= \frac{8}{7} \arctan u+C $$
$$ = \frac{8}{7} \arctan\left(\frac{x}{7}\right)+C $$